# Feature selection using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-algebra, feature-selection

Is there any package in R that contains algorithm for feature selection using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Appendix A [here](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00004038/01/PracticalFS.pdf), for a Matlab code implementation of Forward selection with Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. If nothing else is found, at least you could rewrite it in R.

Answer (score 2):

See "A New Method for Generating the Design Matrix of a Linear Regression Model" by Adel M. Hallawa and Abdul-Mordy H. Azzam in The Egyptian Statistical Journal, ISSR, Cairo University

Answer (score 0):

The "far" package has it.

Use Rseek.  It's the second thing that came up in a search.

Comment: "far" package has only orthogonalization method which is easy to find. Actually I can use QR decomposition to orthogonalize a matrix, but it isn't aim of my question. What I'm looking for is algorithm using this orthogonalization method.

Comment: I guess I was thrown in this from the documentation for far ----- 
"orthonormalization - Orthonormalization of a set of a matrix
Description: Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of a matrix considering its columns as vectors. Normalization is provided as will."